# Volume by integrals of an icosahedron

Tags: integration

I want to know if there is an easy way to find the volume of a convex icosahedron using integrals. My problem is that I don't know how to determine what the integration limits are.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: What do you mean by convex icosahedron? You could use the symmetry of the object and split the volume into 20 equal parts or better pyramids. Then determine the volume of the pyramid, which can be parametrized in order to calculate it via a integral.

Comment: I though about this method but it seems really hard to do. Is there an easier way?

Comment: And I mean by a convex icosahedron that ://www.google.es/search?q=convex+icosahedron&oq=convex+icos&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.4424j0j7&client=ms-android-bq&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=nMjRZ5LkNxTpXM:

Comment: I don't think there's an "easy way". As an integration exercise it doesn't strike me as informative. If you just want the answer it's here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the divergence theorem. That is, the divergence theorem states that
$$\iiint_V \nabla \cdot F dV = \iint_S F \cdot n dS,$$
where $S$ is the surface of the region enclosed by $F$. Choose $F=\frac{1}{3}(x,y,z)$ (or anything such that the divergence is 1) and compute the surface integral over each face of your polyhedron.

Integral over each face will be integrating over a polyhedron in the plane. So in essence, you integrate over the projection of the faces.